# Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?

Tags: iterator, rust

It can be useful to iterate over multiple variables at once, overlapping ([`slice::windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows)), or not ([`slice::chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks)).

This only works for slices; is it possible to do this for iterators, using tuples for convenience?

Something like the following could be written:

```
for (prev, next) in some_iter.windows(2) {
    ...
}
```

If not, could it be implemented as a trait on existing iterators?

Comment: You could easily do an `iter_pairs`, `iter_triples` once you decide what to do if there aren't enough items at the end, but not a generic "any size tuple" one with Rust at the moment.

Comment: If there aren't enough it would do nothing, as with slice functions.

Comment: This was pointed out to me on IRC `https://docs.rs/itertools/*/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows` would like to look into its code before posting answer though.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### On stable

Since Rust 1.51 this is possible with **const generics** where the iterator yields constant size arrays **`[T; N]`** for any `N`.

I built the [`itermore`](https://crates.io/crates/itermore) crate which implements both of these, providing the [`array_chunks()`](https://docs.rs/itermore/latest/itermore/trait.IterArrayChunks.html#method.array_chunks) and [`array_windows()`](https://docs.rs/itermore/latest/itermore/trait.IterArrayWindows.html#method.array_windows) methods under separate extension traits.

```rust
use itermore::IterArrayChunks; // 0.7

for [a, b, c] in some_iter.by_ref().array_chunks() {
    ...
}

let rem = some_iter.into_remainder();
```

```rust
use itermore::IterArrayWindows; // 0.7

for [prev, next] in some_iter.array_windows() {
    ...
}
```

Using the example given in the `Itertools` answer:

```
use itermore::IterArrayChunks; // 0.7

fn main() {
    let some_iter = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].into_iter();

    for [prev, next] in some_iter.array_chunks() {
        println!("{}--{}", prev, next);
    }
}
```

This outputs

```
1--2
3--4
5--6
```

Most times the array size can be inferred but you can also specific it explicitly. Additionally, any reasonable size `N` can be used, there is no limit like in the `Itertools` case.

```rust
use itermore::IterArrayWindows; // 0.7

fn main() {
    let mut iter = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].into_iter().array_windows::<5>();
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
    println!("{:?}", iter.next());
}
```

This outputs

```
Some([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
Some([2, 3, 4, 5, 6])
None
```

Note: `array_windows()` uses clone to yield elements multiple times so its best used for references and cheap to copy types.

### On nightly

The chunks version is now available on nightly under the name [`array_chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.array_chunks)

```
#![feature(iter_array_chunks)]

for [a, b, c] in some_iter.array_chunks() {
    ...
}
```

And it handles remainders nicely:

```
#![feature(iter_array_chunks)]

for [a, b, c] in some_iter.by_ref().array_chunks() {
    ...
}

let rem = some_iter.into_remainder();
```

### Performance

The iterator versions are particularly useful if you are not iterating over some contiguous collection. However, depending on your use-case you might find that collecting into a `Vec` first and using the slice methods might be faster even including the time allocate the iterator into a `Vec`. This is particularly true in the case of `array_windows` where the elements need to be cloned.

Comment: note that this will drop off any remainder entries if not divisible by the given chunk size.

Answer (score 50):

It's possible to take chunks of an iterator using [`Itertools::tuples`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuples), up to a 4-tuple:

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn main() {
    let some_iter = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].into_iter();

    for (prev, next) in some_iter.tuples() {
        println!("{}--{}", prev, next);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=7742f0716b13224e9982bbca72d999be))

```
1--2
3--4
5--6
```

If you don't know that your iterator exactly fits into the chunks, you can use [`Tuples::into_buffer`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/structs/struct.Tuples.html#method.into_buffer) to access any leftovers:

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn main() {
    let some_iter = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5].into_iter();

    let mut t = some_iter.tuples();
    for (prev, next) in t.by_ref() {
        println!("{}--{}", prev, next);
    }
    for leftover in t.into_buffer() {
        println!("{}", leftover);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=d93062b2b97200a1ee45b23ba08be502))

```
1--2
3--4
5
```

It's also possible to take up to 4-tuple windows with [`Itertools::tuple_windows`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows):

```rust
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.9.0

fn main() {
    let some_iter = vec![1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6].into_iter();

    for (prev, next) in some_iter.tuple_windows() {
        println!("{}--{}", prev, next);
    }
}
```

([playground](https://play.integer32.com/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=a7ccc9075a58559fbcb8dfb10a1521ce))

```
1--2
2--3
3--4
4--5
5--6
```

If you need to get partial chunks / windows, you can get

Comment: Would it work with a tuple of 3 elements? Looking at the doc it seems it could be possible.

Comment: @MatthieuM. yep, but the number of implementations *is* limited to a 4-tuple (which I've added).

Comment: Yes, well... in the absence of variadics it's otherwise painful to implement I guess (and bulky too).

Comment: Was this removed from the latest version of itertools? I can't see it [here](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.6/itertools/).

Comment: @dshepherd I continue to see both methods. I've updated the links to the documentation and provided playground links.

Comment: Ah, I was looking at the list of free functions rather than the list of functions on the itertools trait.

Comment: This does not handle the case where the input is not divisible by the chunk length, right? So it is **not** an equivalent of `chunk`.

Comment: @Bakuriu you can get the remaining pieces via [`Tuples::into_buffer`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.9.0/itertools/structs/struct.Tuples.html#method.into_buffer)

Answer (score 34):

**TL;DR**: The best way to have `chunks` and `windows` on an arbitrary iterator/collection is to first `collect` it into a `Vec` and iterate over *that*.

---

The exact syntax requested is impossible in Rust.

The issue is that in Rust, a function's signature is depending on *types*, not *values*, and while Dependent Typing exists, there are few languages that implement it (it's hard).

This is why `chunks` and `windows` return a sub-slice by the way; the number of elements in a `&[T]` is not part of the type and therefore can be decided at run-time.

---

Let's pretend you asked for: `for slice in some_iter.windows(2)` instead then.

Where would the storage backing this slice live?

It cannot live:

- in the original collection because a `LinkedList` doesn't have a contiguous storage
- in the iterator because of the definition of `Iterator::Item`, there is no lifetime available

So, unfortunately, slices can only be used when the backing storage is a slice.

---

If dynamic allocations are accepted, then it is possible to use `Vec<Iterator::Item>` as the `Item` of the chunking iterator.

```
struct Chunks<I: Iterator> {
    elements: Vec<<I as Iterator>::Item>,
    underlying: I,
}

impl<I: Iterator> Chunks<I> {
    fn new(iterator: I, size: usize) -> Chunks<I> {
        assert!(size > 0);

        let mut result = Chunks {
           underlying: iterator, elements: Vec::with_capacity(size)
        };
        result.refill(size);
        result
    }

    fn refill(&mut self, size: usize) {
        assert!(self.elements.is_empty());

        for _ in 0..size {
            match self.underlying.next() {
                Some(item) => self.elements.push(item),
                None => break,
            }
        }
    }
}

impl<I: Iterator> Iterator for Chunks<I> {
    type Item = Vec<<I as Iterator>::Item>;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.elements.is_empty() {
            return None;
        }

        let new_elements = Vec::with_capacity(self.elements.len());
        let result = std::mem::replace(&mut self.elements, new_elements);

        self.refill(result.len());

        Some(result)
    }
}

fn main() {
    let v = vec!(1, 2, 3, 4, 5);

    for slice in Chunks::new(v.iter(), 2) {
        println!("{:?}", slice);
    }
}
```

Will return:

> ```
> [1, 2]
> [3, 4]
> [5]
> ```

---

The canny reader will realize that I surreptitiously switched from `windows` to `chunks`.

`windows` is more difficult, because it returns the same element multiple times which require that the element be `Clone`. Also, since it needs returning a full `Vec` each time, it will need internally to keep a `Vec<Vec<Iterator::Item>>`.

This is left as an exercise to the reader.

---

Finally, a note on **performance**: all those allocations are gonna hurt (especially in the `windows` case).

The best allocation strategy is generally to allocate a single chunk of memory and then live off that (unless the amount is really massive, in which case streaming is required).

It's called `collect::<Vec<_>>()` in Rust.

And since the `Vec` has a `chunks` and `windows` methods (by virtue of implementing `Deref<Target=[T]>`), you can then use that instead:

```
for slice in v.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>().chunks(2) {
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}

for slice in v.iter().collect::<Vec<_>>().windows(2) {
    println!("{:?}", slice);
}
```

Sometimes the best solutions are the simplest.

Comment: Sorry to downvote, but *The exact syntax requested is impossible in Rust* is not true; please check [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42139758/155423). Most of the rest of your analysis makes sense though.

Comment: @Shepmaster: Your answer does not have the exact syntax requested either. The request is `for (prev, next) in some_iter.windows(2)`, with 2 a runtime parameter, which I interpret as meaning that I could pass 3 and have `for (n0, n1, n2) in some_iter.windows(3)` and that's impossible. You chose to focus on `(prev, next)` and ignore the runtime parameter, it may be OK with the OP, but as far as I am concerned this is not what they asked for (and I don't read minds).

Comment: A good point. specifying *both* the tuple size and an argument to `windows` would not make sense, especially if there was a mismatch. I might encourage you to draw explicit attention to that in your answer - perhaps adding an example?

Comment: @Shepmaster: I am not quite sure what kind of example you mean; I already cited that types cannot depend on values unless one uses Dependent Typing and I am at a loss at how to illustrate it to be honest. Maybe it's not that important since your answer is clearly better.

Comment: Your answer makes a lot of sense, but I cannot help but feel that the lack of `chunks` and `windows` on iterators is an issue. As you had already so, it's actually really easy to implement `chunks` with a dynamic allocation of only c elements where c is the size of the chunk; in contrast using `collect::<Vec<_>>` and then chunking means we need a dynamic allocation of n elements where n is the total number of elements produced by the iterators. Your `chunks` example can be optimized to do a single allocation, so performance won't hurt.

Comment: > `This is left as an exercise to the reader.`

the `windows` functionality described here is exactly what I am looking for but I am not sure how to implement it, still new to Rust. Is there an example?

Answer (score 0):

This is possible using the standard library only with arrays (not tuples but similar and even better convenience), using the [`Iterator::array_chunks()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.array_chunks) and [`Iterator::map_windows()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.map_windows) functions. Note there isn't a general `array_windows()` function, because such function won't be zero-cost (it will have to clone the elements). Instead, you are provided with a **reference** to an array of elements, and if you want the behavior of `array_windows()` you can just clone it.