# Creating a sliding window iterator of slices of chars from a String

Tags: string, utf-8, rust, iterator, slice

I am looking for the best way to go from `String` to `Windows<T>` using the `windows` function provided for [slices.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows)

I understand how to use windows this way:

```
fn main() {
    let tst = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g'];
    let mut windows = tst.windows(3);

    // prints ['a', 'b', 'c']
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
    // prints ['b', 'c', 'd']
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
    // etc...
}
```

But I am a bit lost when working this problem:

```
fn main() {
    let tst = String::from("abcdefg");
    let inter = ? //somehow create slice of character from tst
    let mut windows = inter.windows(3);

    // prints ['a', 'b', 'c']
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
    // prints ['b', 'c', 'd']
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
    // etc...
}
```

Essentially, I am looking for how to convert a string into a char slice that I can use the window method with.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This solution will work for your purpose. ([playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9dfb246183e4d204323cf8cfc8322fa8&version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015))

```
fn main() {
    let tst = String::from("abcdefg");
    let inter = tst.chars().collect::<Vec<char>>();
    let mut windows = inter.windows(3);

    // prints ['a', 'b', 'c']
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
    // prints ['b', 'c', 'd']
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
    // etc...
    println!("{:?}", windows.next().unwrap());
}
```

String can iterate over its chars, but it's not a slice, so you have to collect it into a vec, which then coerces into a slice.

Answer (score 18):

The problem that you are facing is that `String` is really represented as something like a `Vec<u8>` under the hood, with some APIs to let you access `char`s. In UTF-8 the representation of a code point can be anything from 1 to 4 bytes, and they are all compacted together for space-efficiency.

The only slice you could get directly of an entire `String`, without copying everything, would be a `&[u8]`, but you wouldn't know if the bytes corresponded to whole or just parts of code points.

The `char` type corresponds exactly to a code point, and therefore has a size of 4 bytes, so that it can accommodate any possible value. So, if you build a slice of `char` by copying from a `String`, the result could be up to 4 times larger.

To avoid making a potentially large, temporary memory allocation, you should consider a more lazy approach – iterate through the `String`, making slices at exactly the `char` boundaries. Something like this:

```
fn char_windows<'a>(src: &'a str, win_size: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item = &'a str> {
    src.char_indices()
        .flat_map(move |(from, _)| {
            src[from ..].char_indices()
                .skip(win_size - 1)
                .next()
                .map(|(to, c)| {
                    &src[from .. from + to + c.len_utf8()]
                })
    })
}
```

This will give you an iterator where the items are `&str`, each with 3 `char`s:

```
let mut windows = char_windows(&tst, 3);

for win in windows {
    println!("{:?}", win);
}
```

The nice thing about this approach is that it hasn't done any copying at all - each `&str` produced by the iterator is still a slice into the original source `String`.

---

All of that complexity is because Rust uses UTF-8 encoding for strings by default. If you *absolutely know* that your input string doesn't contain any multi-byte characters, you can treat it as ASCII bytes, and taking slices becomes easy:

```
let tst = String::from("abcdefg");
let inter = tst.as_bytes();
let mut windows = inter.windows(3);
```

However, you now have slices of bytes, and you'll need to turn them back into strings to do anything with them:

```
for win in windows {
    println!("{:?}", String::from_utf8_lossy(win));
}
```

Comment: This was an awesome explanation of what is going on under the hood - thanks for shedding light on it!

Comment: [Here's](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=079a336828c59cdbce00404a4f6b42b4) a playground link with `char_windows` plus a slight modification to demonstrate an equivalent for [`Chunks`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.chunks)

Answer (score 9):

You can use [itertools](https://crates.io/crates/itertools) to walk over windows of any iterator, up to a width of 4:

```
extern crate itertools; // 0.7.8

use itertools::Itertools;

fn main() {
    let input = "日本語";

    for (a, b) in input.chars().tuple_windows() {
        println!("{}, {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

See also:

- [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134874/155423)