# How do I check if a slice is sorted?

Tags: sorting, iterator, rust, slice

How do I check if a slice is sorted?

Assuming a function that accepts a slice of `i32`, is there an idiomatic Rust way of checking if the slice is sorted?

```
fn is_sorted(data: &[i32]) -> bool {
    // ...
}
```

Would it be possible to generalize the above method so that it would accept an iterator?

```
fn is_sorted<I>(iter: I)
where 
    I: Iterator, 
    I::Item: Ord,
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Test that every subsequent element consistently more or less than the previous?

Comment: For record, there is currently an RFC for adding `is_sorted` to the standard library https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/2351.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I'd grab pairs of elements and assert they are all in ascending (or descending, depending on what you mean by "sorted") order:

```
fn is_sorted<T>(data: &[T]) -> bool
where
    T: Ord,
{
    data.windows(2).all(|w| w[0] <= w[1])
}

fn main() {
    assert!(is_sorted::<u8>(&[]));
    assert!(is_sorted(&[1]));
    assert!(is_sorted(&[1, 2, 3]));
    assert!(is_sorted(&[1, 1, 1]));
    assert!(!is_sorted(&[1, 3, 2]));
    assert!(!is_sorted(&[3, 2, 1]));
}
```

Ditto for generic iterators:

```
extern crate itertools; // 0.7.8

use itertools::Itertools;

fn is_sorted<I>(data: I) -> bool
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Ord + Clone,
{
    data.into_iter().tuple_windows().all(|(a, b)| a <= b)
}

fn main() {
    assert!(is_sorted(&[] as &[u8]));
    assert!(is_sorted(&[1]));
    assert!(is_sorted(&[1, 2, 3]));
    assert!(is_sorted(&[1, 1, 1]));
    assert!(!is_sorted(&[1, 3, 2]));
    assert!(!is_sorted(&[3, 2, 1]));
}
```

See also:

- [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42134874/155423)

In nightly Rust, there are unstable methods to accomplish this:

- [`slice::is_sorted`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.is_sorted)
- [`slice::is_sorted_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.is_sorted_by)
- [`slice::is_sorted_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.is_sorted_by_key)
- [`Iterator::is_sorted`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.is_sorted)
- [`Iterator::is_sorted_by`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.is_sorted_by)
- [`Iterator::is_sorted_by_key`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.is_sorted_by_key)

Comment: @PeterHall I dunno; usually either you keep a collection sorted by construction (e.g. always adding new values in the "right" place) or by some type invariant (e.g. `BTreeSet`). Have *you* ever wanted to check if something is sorted? :-D Besides, then you have to deal with *which* "sorted" do you mean, and then sorted by a key, etc.

Comment: @Shepmaster "*Have you ever wanted to check if something is sorted?*" -- Quite often, actually: **unit tests and pre/post-condition checks**. [I've written a few more words about this here](https://github.com/LukasKalbertodt/rfcs/blob/rfc-add-is-sorted/text/0000-is-sorted.md#motivation) ;-)

Comment: I find it quite noticeable, that this requires a (total) order, rather than a  partial order. Never thought about this.

Answer (score 5):

It is not necessary to have `Clone` for an iterator `is_sorted` implementation. Here is a no-dependency Rust implementation of `is_sorted`:

```
fn is_sorted<I>(data: I) -> bool
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Ord,
{
    let mut it = data.into_iter();
    match it.next() {
        None => true,
        Some(first) => it.scan(first, |state, next| {
            let cmp = *state <= next;
            *state = next;
            Some(cmp)
        }).all(|b| b),
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One more using [`try_fold()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.try_fold):

```rust
pub fn is_sorted<T: IntoIterator>(t: T) -> bool
where
    <T as IntoIterator>::Item: std::cmp::PartialOrd,
{
    let mut iter = t.into_iter();

    if let Some(first) = iter.next() {
        iter.try_fold(first, |previous, current| {
            (previous > current).then_some(current)
        })
        .is_some()
    } else {
        true
    }
}
```

Comment: Since the addition of `bool::then_some` the inner could be changed to `(previous <= current).then_some(current)`, using `.is_some()` on the result:
`iter.next().map(|first| iter.try_fold(first, |previous, current| (previous <= current).then_some(previous)).is_some()).unwrap_or(true)`