# Rust iterator something like chunks()

Tags: rust, iterator

This iterator

```rust
let data = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

for x in data.chunks(2) {
    println!("{:?}", x);
}
```

will produce

```
[0, 1]
[2, 3]
[4, 5]
```

Can I use iterator to get something like this.

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
```

I know how to do that using for loop. But can iterator do this better?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are there equivalents to slice::chunks/windows for iterators to loop over pairs, triplets etc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134874/are-there-equivalents-to-slicechunks-windows-for-iterators-to-loop-over-pairs)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess your can use  [Itertools.tuple_windows](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.7.6/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.tuple_windows) for this. According to the documentation it *"returns an iterator over all contiguous windows producing tuples of a specific size (up to 4)"* :

```rust
use itertools::Itertools;
use itertools::TupleWindows;
use std::slice::Iter;

let data = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let it: TupleWindows<Iter<'_, i32>, (&i32, &i32)> = data.iter().tuple_windows();

for elem in it {
    println!("{:?}", elem);
}
```

Output:

```
(0, 1)
(1, 2)
(2, 3)
(3, 4)
(4, 5)
```

**Edit**:
As noted in [comment1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822952/rust-iterator-something-like-chunks/65823181?noredirect=1#comment116381474_65823181) by @Masklinn and [comment2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65822952/rust-iterator-something-like-chunks/65823181?noredirect=1#comment116382554_65823181) by @SebastianRedl, you can also use [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) from stdlib and avoid including `Itertools` in your project. But note that it only works for slices (or things that coerce to slices), not general iterators (which is fine in your case).

```rust
let data = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

let it = data.windows(2);

for elem in it {
    println!("{:?}", elem);
}
```

Output:

```
[0, 1]
[1, 2]
[2, 3]
[3, 4]
[4, 5]
```

Comment: FWIW there's [`windows`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.slice.html#method.windows) in the stdlib which iterates on slices and would probably be sufficient here.

Comment: @Masklinn thanks, I edited my answer to include your suggestion.

Comment: @mgc You should note in your answer that `windows` works only for slices (or things that coerce to them), not general iterators.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively, without extra dependencies, you can zip the same iterator, skip one item on the second one.

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = vec![0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    let i1 = data.iter();
    let i2 = data.iter();
    for (a, b) in i1.zip(i2.skip(1)) {
        println!("{} {}", a, b);
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=4079ac666a58098f1ff6924574ecb952)

Comment: This is much easier.