# Splitting a UTF-8 string into chunks

Tags: string, rust, iterator

I want to split a UTF-8 string into chunks of equal size. I came up with a solution that does exactly that. Now I want to simplify it removing the first collect call if possible. Is there a way to do it?

```rust
fn main() {
    let strings = "ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚĆŹŻ"
        .chars()
        .collect::<Vec<char>>()
        .chunks(3)
        .map(|chunk| chunk.iter().collect::<String>())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("{:?}", strings);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=fn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20let%20strings%20%3D%20%22%C4%84%C4%86%C4%98%C5%81%C5%83%C3%93%C5%9A%C4%86%C5%B9%C5%BB%22%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.chars()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect%3A%3A%3CVec%3Cchar%3E%3E()%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.chunks(3)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.map(%7Cchunk%7C%20chunk.iter().collect%3A%3A%3CString%3E())%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20.collect%3A%3A%3CVec%3CString%3E%3E()%3B%0A%20%20%20%20println!(%22%7B%3A%3F%7D%22%2C%20strings)%3B%0A%7D%0A)

Comment: Seems like, in order to get chunks, you need to collect into vectors. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42134874/are-there-equivalents-to-slicechunks-windows-for-iterators-to-loop-over-pairs

Comment: As always with unicode strings you need to be careful about exactly what you mean by "equal sized chunks". You may want to be considering graphemes rather than characters - since this will split up combining characters and combining emoji.

Comment: Here's an example of the issues raised by @MichaelAnderson: [playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=0d361c546c6b69fe68bf644e76114b13)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having considered the problem with graphemes I ended up with the following solution.

I used the [unicode-segmentation](https://crates.io/crates/unicode-segmentation) crate.

```rust
use unicode_segmentation::UnicodeSegmentation;                                                                                                                            

fn main() {
    let strings = "ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚĆŹŻèèèèè"
        .graphemes(true)                                                                                                                                          
        .collect::<Vec<&str>>()                                                                                                                                   
        .chunks(length)                                                                                                                                           
        .map(|chunk| chunk.concat())                                                                                                                              
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("{:?}", strings);
}
```

I hope some simplifications can still be made.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`chunks()` from `Itertools`](https://docs.rs/itertools/0.10.1/itertools/trait.Itertools.html#method.chunks).

```
use itertools::Itertools; // 0.10.1

fn main() {
    let strings = "ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚĆŹŻ"
        .chars()
        .chunks(3)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|chunk| chunk.collect::<String>())
        .collect::<Vec<String>>();
    println!("{:?}", strings);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

This doesn't require `Itertools` as a dependency and also does not allocate, as it iterates over slices of the original string:

```
fn chunks(s: &str, length: usize) -> impl Iterator<Item=&str> {
    assert!(length > 0);
    let mut indices = s.char_indices().map(|(idx, _)| idx).peekable();
    
    std::iter::from_fn(move || {
        let start_idx = match indices.next() {
            Some(idx) => idx,
            None => return None,
        };
        for _ in 0..length - 1 {
            indices.next();
        }
        let end_idx = match indices.peek() {
            Some(idx) => *idx,
            None => s.bytes().len(),
        };
        Some(&s[start_idx..end_idx])
    })
}


fn main() {
    let strings = chunks("ĄĆĘŁŃÓŚĆŹŻ", 3).collect::<Vec<&str>>();
    println!("{:?}", strings);
}
```